# Natural translation for "Everything worth doing requires self-discipline and effort"

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

What would be the most natural way to say, "Everything worth doing requires self-discipline and effort?"

每個值得的事情都需要磨練和努力 feels like English crammed into Chinese.

Would 每件值得的事都需要磨練和努力 be better？

1) What's the most natural Mandarin translation?

2) What's the most natural Cantonese translation?

Comment: how about 任何 instead of 每个? re 磨练 bkrs: to temper oneself
to steel oneself
self-discipline
endurance, alternatively 自律?
submit E to iciba get: 任何值得做的事都需要自律和努力

Comment: @user6065 or just simply 「凡事」 for "everything worth doing", the word "worth" here seemed redundant to me so I just skip it.

Comment: It would be helpful if OP could clarify the context - the meaning of "everything worth doing".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the phrase:

**好事多磨**

*ABC Proverbs* defines it as:

> **Lit** [Accomplishing] great things [has] many hardships.
>
> **Fig** In accomplishing anything worthwhile, one is bound to encounter setbacks.
>
> **Note**: originally hǎoshì referred to a successful marriage or engagement, so “it takes many twists and turns to accomplish a good marriage” is sometimes equated with “The course of true love never did run smooth.” Cf. JW, chap. 28; DRC, chap. 1; Èr Kè Pāi'àn Jīngqí, chap. 9.

There was a headline from an hour ago on 速途网 that reads:

> EOS主网的艰难启动是好事多磨，还是持币者的投机心理大于信仰?

Comment: thanks so much! is ABC Proverbs a book or website? if book, are you referring to this: https://www.amazon.com/ABC-Dictionary-Chinese-Proverbs-Yanyu/dp/0824827708?

Comment: @Crashalot That’s the book! I’m using the digital version in Pleco. I’d go with the digital over paper version any day but each to their own.

Answer (score 1):

You may lookup an idiom (成語) from the dictionary that matches what you want to say. It would sound more natural.
For example, 全力以赴, 孜孜不倦, 自強不息, (should not) 守株待兔, (should not) 半途而廢.

Most Chinese idioms are understood by both Cantonese and Mandarin speakers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 凡事都需要自律和努力.
"Self-discipline" is not reflected in the original translation.

Answer (score 0):

每個值得的事情都需要磨練和努力 is more accurate than 每件重要的事都需要磨練和努力。
Because of worth meaning(值得), not important（重要）

Comment: Sorry, how about 每件值得的事都需要磨練和努力?